# show Loading effect in jquery UI tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have tooltip which is being displayed on hover of a image,
The content of tooltip is the larger version hovered image..

**Problem:** The image in tooltip loads slowly.. How can I display loader until image doesn't loads in Tootip?

```
<img id="small-img" title= "<img id='big-img' src=<?=getResizedImage(imageId, 500);?>>" src="<?= getResizedImage(imageId, 150); ?>" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause an error in your HTML? `title="<img id="...` escape the `html` chars

Comment: Please Please ignore such things.. I have properly working tooltip there

Comment: And you're not able to define in css a `background-image` for the container? or did you already try it?

Comment: Yes, I Have background-image for the container, Whenever I hover the image first the tooltip container appears in small size then the the container gets bigger and show background-image and slowly loading image.

Comment: Maybe give the container a fixed width?

Comment: Do you want the loader or are you fine with a tooltip displayed after loading? because then you can handle it with `$('img').on('load', function(){[...]});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the contents of 'title' to other DIV ('tooltip-contents')..

Below is my fix which shows a div inside tooltip.

```
//Image to be hovered to show Tooltip
<img id="small-img" src="<?= getImage(imageId, 150); ?>" />

//Contents to be displayed in Tooltip.
<div id="tooltip-contents" style="display:none;">
    <img src='<?= getImage(imageId, 500); ?>'/>
</div>

//Contents of .js
$('#small-img').attr('title', function(){
    return $('#tooltip-contents').html();
});

$("#small-img").tooltip({
    options : {
        content : function() {
            return $(this).prop('title');;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the `image` with a `container` and add a `background-image` for the `container.
If I understood right your img-big will be shown in tooltip?

Comment: Can you please look the question again.. I was missing something in question previously